# Convert Column type to integer after using paste collapse function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe in R:

| 3_utr_start | 3_utr_end | count | freq | entrezgene_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 299336 | 303353 | 1268 | 13.66 | 55344 |
| 299339 | 303360 | 1280 | 14.25 | 55346 |

I would like to combine the two rows into one row so that the output is like this:

| entrezgene_id | 3_utr_start | 3_utr_end | count | freq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55344 | 299336 299339 | 303353 303360 | 1268 1280 | 13.66 14.25 |

I used the following code to get the second table:

```
library(dplyr)

result_final = result_3p %>%
  group_by(entrezgene_id) %>%
  summarize(`3_utr_start` = paste(`3_utr_start`, collapse = "  "), `3_utr_end` = paste(`3_utr_end`, collapse = "  "), count = paste(count, collapse = "  "), freq = paste(freq, collapse = "  "))
```

But this converts the type of columns from **int** to **character**. I would like to save the numbers as int and not character.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using `paste()` converts them to strings because you cannot enumerate the number `1 2`. You need to make them lists If you want to preserve them as integers, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(entrezgene_id) %>% 
 summarise_all(list)

# A tibble: 1 × 5
#  entrezgene_id X3_utr_start X3_utr_end count     freq     
#          <int> <list>       <list>     <list>    <list>   
#1         55344 <int [2]>    <int [2]>  <int [2]> <dbl [2]>
```

Comment: You can use `unnest()` but that will bring it back to its original form (`df %>% group_by(entrezgene_id) %>% summarise_all(list) %>% unnest()`). What do you mean generate the list?

Comment: Thanks, I understood what you meant!